# Extract function names in python code using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex, parsing

I am using `prism.js` to highlight python code but for some reasons it is not highlighting function names which are called for example `deep_flatten()` or `flatten([1,2,3])` or `flatten(list(map(lambda x: x*2,[1,2,3])))`.

So made the following code to overcome this problem

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('code')].forEach(x => {
      x.innerText = x.innerText.replace(/(\w+)\([^\(\)]*\)/gi,match=>{
        if(match.match(/^\d/)){
             return match
                              }

        else {
              return `<span class="called-function">${match}</span>`
            }

        }
   })
```

It works fine for the first two ones but fails for the other two ones.
On doing google search I found that this is called something recursive and can be done only with parsers. On searching for python parsers in javscript I found a lot of them but they are very big and for parsing whole code.

How can I make a parser/regex which extracts all function names and encloses them within `span` tags.

I don't want the specific code just some psuedo-code or algorithm as to how to proceed.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't sufficient for parsing a non-regular language such as python.

Comment: You can use the `regex` module, which is a whole lot bigger than any code parsing module. Then use @NahuelFouilleul recursion style regex. Or, you could just make a function that calls itself when it encounters a `(`. Ie. make your own stack. It's easy.

Comment: Oh, but JS can't do regex recursion. Easier to do code recursion if you can access the string elements.

Answer (score 0):

The default re package in std libs can't handle recursive regexes, however seems the `regex` package can

```
/(\w+)\([^\(\)]*\)/gi
```

can be changed to

```
/(\w+)(\((?:[^\(\)]|(?2))*\))/gi
```

Comment: SyntaxError :( Invalid regexp group

Comment: which library are you using, i told about `regex` library not `re`

Comment: How to use the regex library in javascript?

Comment: maybe misread because of python in the title, answer is for python, javascript regex doesn't handle recursive regex a weak workaround could be to ensure `(` and `)` are even: for example `(\w+)(?=(?:(?:[()][^()]*){2})+$)`

Comment: Prism.js works for javascript functions so I am using that regex. It is `"function":/[a-z0-9_]+(?=\()/i,number:/\b-?(?:0x[\da-f]+|\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)\b/i`. Later I will write a recursive function or something else to handle it.